# Syntax highlighting of VS code broken with heredoc

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

[image: VS code's syntax highlighting broke here]

As the picture illustrates, syntax highlighting breaks after heredoc(_HTML in this case). How can I do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why a space between `<<<` and `_HTML`? Also, no space is allowed before `_HTML;`

Comment: Update and include the code block in the question please

Comment: Are you on php 7.3+ and is VS setup to recognize php 7.3+? If not, the end of the heredoc needs to be at the start of the line.

Comment: A typical Heredoc syntax [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Okay the problem is solved. I did not realize that no space is allowed before _HTML. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Mentioned by lovelace, what does it mean to update and include the code block? Does it mean I should include all of the codes in the picture? Sorry for being stupid if  so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails, as AbraCadaver said, because your Heredoc is invalid (for PHP <7.3). Put your closing _HTML at the very first offset in the line.

Otherwise it will think, that you didn´t close it and therefore will display it, as the string would continue (because it does).

Comment: Please be aware that the syntax is valid as of PHP/7.3—it's only a problem in earlier versions. In any case, VSCode syntax highlighter does not really support 100% of the language syntax anyway.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the PHP7.3 notice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tabs on the _HTML line.